# Filter application's method calls in Android trace file

Tags: android, debugging

I have started to research about Android applications. So, for dynamic analyzing of applications, I need to do some `Data` and `Control Flaw` stuffs. I use the [startMethodTracing](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging) to collect the trace file and I can view the trace file using [Android Device Monitor](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html).

Unfortunately, the trace file contains both system and application calls. For example, in order to call `setText` method of `EditText` widget, the trace file includes logs as follows:

```
0x71aefac0  android.widget.TextView checkForRelayout    ()V TextView.java
0x71aefaf0  android.widget.TextView checkForResize  ()V TextView.java
0x71aefbe0  android.widget.TextView createEditorIfNeeded    ()V TextView.java
0x71aefd00  android.widget.TextView getBoxHeight    (Landroid/text/Layout;)I    TextView.java
0x71aefd30  android.widget.TextView getDesiredHeight    ()I TextView.java
0x71aefd60  android.widget.TextView getDesiredHeight    (Landroid/text/Layout;Z)I   TextView.java
0x71aefdf0  android.widget.TextView getLayoutAlignment  ()Landroid/text/Layout$Alignment;   TextView.java
0x71af0000  android.widget.TextView invalidateCursor    (III)V  TextView.java
0x71af0150  android.widget.TextView isMultilineInputType    (I)Z    TextView.java
0x71af0240  android.widget.TextView makeSingleLayout    (ILandroid/text/BoringLayout$Metrics;ILandroid/text/Layout$Alignment;ZLandroid/text/TextUtils$TruncateAt;Z)Landroid/text/Layout;    TextView.java
0x71af0300  android.widget.TextView registerForPreDraw  ()V TextView.java
0x71af0390  android.widget.TextView removeIntersectingNonAdjacentSpans  (IILjava/lang/Class;)V  TextView.java
0x71af0480  android.widget.TextView sendBeforeTextChanged   (Ljava/lang/CharSequence;III)V  TextView.java
0x71af04b0  android.widget.TextView setFilters  (Landroid/text/Editable;[Landroid/text/InputFilter;)V   TextView.java
0x71af0630  android.widget.TextView setText (Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Landroid/widget/TextView$BufferType;ZI)V   TextView.java
0x71af0690  android.widget.TextView shouldAdvanceFocusOnEnter   ()Z TextView.java
0x71af07b0  android.widget.TextView stopMarquee ()V TextView.java
```

I want to filter the method calls that done by the application like below:

```
0x71af0630  android.widget.TextView setText (Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Landroid/widget/TextView$BufferType;ZI)V   TextView.java
```

Could any one please guide me to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way i can think of is to:

1) Retrieve the apk class names by decompiling it with [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) and just doing a find for ".smali" files. The folders are package and the smali names are the class names.

2) Use [dmtracedump](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html#dmtracedump) to retrieve a dot tree representation of the trace and then drop all the method calls that occur at a depth of 2 or more from the nodes which method calls are from classes of your apk.